# WPF DataGrid Style in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a xaml style for datagrids in my WPF application, I am now writing a custom control that inherits from DataGrid an would like to apply the following style in code behind:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGrid">

    <!-- Make the border and grid lines a little less imposing -->
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#DDDDDD" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalGridLinesBrush" Value="#DDDDDD" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalGridLinesBrush" Value="#DDDDDD" />

    <Setter Property="RowStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <!-- Highlight a grid row as the mouse passes over -->
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Lavender" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="CellStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <!-- Highlight selected rows -->
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Lavender" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Lavender" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <!--StartsEditingOnMouseOver-->
                    <!--<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
                    </Trigger>-->
                </Style.Triggers>

                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewTextInput" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewTextInput" />

                <!-- Add some padding around the contents of a cell -->
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,3,4,3" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

What I have so far is the following code:

```
static DionysusDataGrid()
{

  BorderBrushProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DionysusDataGrid), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFDDDDDD") as Color?));
  HorizontalGridLinesBrushProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DionysusDataGrid), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFDDDDDD") as Color?));
  VerticalGridLinesBrushProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DionysusDataGrid), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFDDDDDD") as Color?));

}
```

But I have no idea how to do the same for the "RowStyle" property which also has a style in itself. And I am also getting the following error when setting the BorderBrushProperty:

```
Default value type does not match type of property 'BorderBrush'."
```

Can anyone help me out?

Thanx

UPDATE:

I resolved the error by updating the code to the following:

```
    static DionysusDataGrid()
{

  BrushConverter converter = new BrushConverter();

  BorderBrushProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DionysusDataGrid), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((System.Windows.Media.Brush)converter.ConvertFromString("#FFDDDDDD")));
  HorizontalGridLinesBrushProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DionysusDataGrid), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((System.Windows.Media.Brush)converter.ConvertFromString("#FFDDDDDD")));
  VerticalGridLinesBrushProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DionysusDataGrid), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((System.Windows.Media.Brush)converter.ConvertFromString("#FFDDDDDD")));

}
```

Comment: Did you try to make a regular cast to non nullable `Color` ? i.e: `(Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFDDDDDD")`

Comment: BorderBrushProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DionysusDataGrid), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFDDDDDD"))); gives the same error.

Comment: Make sure you use the correct namespace for the Color type, checking it against the type of BorderBrush.

Comment: @Baboon to the rescue. Check my update for the correct code. Now to do the row styles in code!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make the Style in code behind, a few general rules apply:

Anything you type in XAML has an equivalent in good old C#:

`<Style ...>` is just [System.Windows.Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.aspx). The same goes for [Setter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.setter.aspx), [Trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger.aspx), you name it.

The only gotcha comes from the `ContentProperty` attribute which is the default property assigned, for example when you do:

```
<TextBlock>My text here!</TextBlock>
```

It sets the `TextBlock.Text` property to `"My text here!"`, because the `TextBlock` class is marked with the attribute `[ContentProperty("Text")]`

And lastly, you need to start from the most nested element when you build from C#:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGrid">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#DDDDDD" />
</Style>
```

Becomes:

```
var brushConverter = new BrushConverter();

var bbSetter = new Setter(
    DataGrid.BorderBrushProperty, 
    brushConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFDDDDDD"));

var style = new Style(typeof(DataGrid));    
style.Setters.Add(bbSetter);
```

From this you should be able to convert any XAML to C#, 
It is useful to note, though, that you can't map any C# to XAML, for example you can't make a dynamic storyboard in XAML, but you can in C#.

Comment: thanx a lot @Baboon!! That helped... I have most of it done and working now, the only part I am struggling with is the Template of the DataGridCell. How can TemplateBinding be done in code?

Comment: @ChrisjanL my google search found: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/240670/WPF-TemplateBinding-in-code . Should work fine I guess.

Comment: Classic case of over thinking a simple solution. I had this style in a resource dictionary and could simply use "this.Style = Application.Current.Resources[typeof(DataGrid)] as Style;". But thanks for all the help, if I ever do need to set style from code behind I have a much better idea of how to do so!